# Cannot create an object of type:oracle.jbo.domain.Date from type:java.lang.String with value:adf.currentDate

Tags: java, jsf, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I'm setting default value for Hire Date as `adf.currentDate` and getting following error:

> JBO-25009: Cannot create an object of type:oracle.jbo.domain.Date from type:java.lang.String with value:adf.currentDate

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem because the attribute in view object is string and you write write its default value adf.currentDate which return oracle.jbo.domain.Date type
So you should 
change data type of attribute to oracle.jbo.domain.Date
or change expression to return string by adf.currentDate.toString

You can read more from below link about dates classes in ADF
http://mahmoudoracle.blogspot.com/2012/03/date-classes-conversion-in-adf.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that u have selected the `Default Value` Type as `Expression` not as `Literal` and the data type of the attribute should `Date` if it is `adf.currentDate` and if it is `adf.currentDateTime` then data type should be `TimeStamp`.